# Video Editing For Android

Tags: android, video

i want to build a app having video editing feature.

These are what I need:

- Mix a new sound track(mp3) into a mp4.
- Adjust sound volume proportion for original mp4 sound track and the new sound track.
- Generate mp4 from images.
- Remove some frames from mp4.

I've found FFMEPG but it's quite complicated.
Is there a easier one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Mix a new sound track into a mp4.

2.Adjust sound volume proportion for original mp4 sound track and the new sound track.

--> Use MP4Parser for adding and removing audio tracks.

checkout this link http://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/

3.Generate mp4 from images.

4.Remove some frames from mp4.

--> Use JCodec to get all frames from mp4 or create mp4 from frames,

checkout this link http://jcodec.org/index.html

Comment: Thank you。I've checked mp4parser, is there a way to adjust the volume for both original sound & new sound?

Comment: For this you need to integrate SoX lib, this actual link http://sox.sourceforge.net/, and its android implementation on SOX https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

Comment: Nope its right link, See the code, they implemented SoX

Comment: Thank you very much! By the way，can I achieve all the tasks using FFMEPG only?

Comment: FFMPEG is slow... but you can.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [JavaCv](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) which wrapps OpenCV, FFmpeg, libdc1394, PGR FlyCapture, OpenKinect, videoInput, ARToolKitPlus, and flandmark. You can easily create video editing application using this.